# how to properly output TCHAR from function?

Tags: c++, tchar

This code:

```
#include <tchar.h>

TCHAR example_function() {
  TCHAR example_tchar[10];
  return example_tchar;
}

int main() { }
```

Gives error:

```
In function 'TCHAR example_function()':
error: invalid conversion from 'TCHAR* {aka char*}' to 'TCHAR {aka char}' [-fpermissive]
warning: address of local variable 'example_tchar' returned [enabled by default]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `example_tchar` is not a `TCHAR`, but an array.

**What are you actually trying to achieve?**

If you want to return a single `TCHAR`:

```
TCHAR example_function() {
  TCHAR example_tchar[10];
  return example_tchar[0];
}
//or simply
TCHAR example_function() {
  TCHAR example_tchar = _T('');
  return example_tchar;
}
```

If you want to return an array, or rather a pointer, you'll have to dynamically allocate memory to prevent undefined behavior:

```
TCHAR* example_function() {
  TCHAR* example_tchar = new TCHAR[10];
  return example_tchar;
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to `delete[]` the received pointer after the usage!

Comment: isn't it returning by value though?

Comment: @silent yes, the pointer is returned by value. But it will point to an invalid address.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to return a *string* of `TCHARs` use something more complex, like `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` for example (or use pointers, or just add set `TCHAR[10]` as return parameter). `TCHAR` is just a define that selects between char and wchar_t based on build options.